# How to select an element uniquely from the list?

Tags: java, selenium, automation

how can i select an element uniquely from this list ?

```
List<WebElement> listout = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("span[class='nav-label']"));  
for (list:listout) {
    list.click();
}
list[1].click();
```

```html
<a _ngcontent-c3="" routerlinkactive="active" class="level-2 expanded ng-star-inserted" href="/rld/(rl:dashboard_tab)">
    <span _ngcontent-c3=""></span>
    <span _ngcontent-c3="" class="nav-label">Status Center</span>
</a>
<<pseudo:before>></<pseudo:before>>
<span _ngcontent-c3=""></span>
<span _ngcontent-c3="" class="nav-label">Status Center</span>
<a _ngcontent-c3="" routerlinkactive="active" class="level-2 expanded ng-star-inserted" href="/rld/(rl:dashboard_tab)">
    <span _ngcontent-c3=""></span>
    <span _ngcontent-c3="" class="nav-label">Status Center</span>
</a>
```

Comment: I don't get what you want to achieve, please invest some time to explain us, what exactly you want to do and which problem are you facing.

Answer (score 0):

Some of things are missing from your code like :

You've defined for each loop like this :

```
for (list:listout) {}
```

Which is not correct , you must have got the compile time error.

It should be like this :

```
 for (WebElement list:listout) {}
```

then you can try this code :

```
List<WebElement> listout = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("span[class='nav-label']"));  
for (WebElement list : listout) {
      if(list.getText().contains("Your Unique element's text")){
       list.click();
 }
}
```

Note that `list[1].click();` should click on second element from your list.
and your css selector this `nav-label` contains the same text **Status Center** , So you will have to write the different css selector or any other locator, as this will not work.